# Github Actions matrix questions

Tags: github, devops, github-actions, pipeline

I just want it to run in Matrix for both INT,STG environments, and for each env I need the longer name (integration,staging).

Does this thing possible within github actions? did I miss something in the sytanx?
I tried looking around for it and couldn't find it..

```
Test:
 name: Deploy Test
 runs-on: ${{matrix.env}}
 strategy:
 matrix:
 env: [int, stg]
 needs: 
      - 'jobA'
      - 'jobB'

 steps:
    - name: Create test things.
 env: 
 ENVIRONMENT: 'if github.runs-on == int; then $ENVIRONMENT=integration else $ENVIRONMENT=staging' 
    - name: Test
 run: |
           some command using ${{env.ENVIRONMENT}} 
          - Desired output is integration

           some command using ${{env.ENVIRONMENT}}
          - Desired output is staging
```

Thanks for anyone willing to assist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runs-on` is used to specify the machine name - you should not put any custom strings there.

The correct format looks like this:

```
Test:
 name: Deploy Test
 runs-on: ubuntu-latest
 strategy:
     matrix:
         env: [int, stg]
 needs: 
      - 'jobA'
      - 'jobB'
 steps:
    - name: Create test things.
    - uses: haya14busa/action-cond@v1
      id: env_name
      with:
        cond: ${{ matrix.env == 'int' }}
        if_true: "integration"
        if_false: "staging"
    - name: Test environment name
      run: |
           some command using ${{ matrix.env }} #int / stg will be passed
           echo ${{ steps.env_name.outputs.value }} # will output integration for int, staging for stg
     - name: Test Staging Only
      if: matrix.env == 'stg'
      run: |
           some command using ${{ matrix.env }} #stg only, skipped for int
           # This only executes for staging
```